# Looping through XML elements and adding to access table

Tags: xml, vb.net, ms-access

Hey I'm trying to loop through elements of my XML, in order to add the contents of each element to an access table. Here is a snapshot of the XML file I'm using:

```
-<XML>
-<cards>
<name>Majespecter Toad - Ogama</name>
<type>Pendulum Effect Monster</type>
<desc>When this card is Normal or Special Summoned: You can Set 1 "Majespecter" Spell/Trap Card directly from your Deck, but it cannot activate this turn. You can only use this effect of "Majespecter Toad - Ogama" once per turn. Cannot be targeted or destroyed </desc>
<race>Spellcaster</race>
<image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/645794.jpg</image_url>
<atk>1300</atk>
<def>500</def>
<level>4</level>
</cards>

-<cards>
<name>Gladiator Beast Retiari</name>
<type>Effect Monster</type>
<desc>When this card is Special Summoned by the effect of a "Gladiator Beast" monster, you can remove from play 1 card from your opponent's Graveyard. At the end of the Battle Phase, if this card attacked or was attacked, you can return it to the Deck to Specia</desc>
<race>Aqua</race>
<image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/612115.jpg</image_url>
<atk>1200</atk>
<def>800</def>
<level>3</level>
</cards>

-<cards>
<name>Malefic Rainbow Dragon</name>
<type>Effect Monster</type>
<desc>This card cannot be Normal Summoned or Set. This card cannot be Special Summoned, except by removing from play 1 "Rainbow Dragon" from your hand or Deck. There can only be 1 face-up "Malefic" monster on the field. Other monsters you control cannot declare</desc>
<race>Dragon</race>
<image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/598988.jpg</image_url>
<atk>4000</atk>
<def>0</def>
<level>10</level>
</cards>
```

This is my code which is supposed to loop through the XML file. The error I'm encountering is: object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ''parse your XML into an XDocument
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\Users\1964\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\YGO Access Test v10\bin\Debug\MyData.xml")
        '' get "Install" element
        Dim install As XElement = doc.Root

        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        conn = New OleDbConnection
        dbprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        Dim databasePath = "Data Source = FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb;"
        conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider & databasePath
        Dim command As OleDbCommand
        Try
            conn.Open()
            command = New OleDbCommand()

            For Each cards As XElement In install.Elements("cards")
                Dim name As String = cards.Element("name").Value
                Dim type As String = cards.Element("type").Value
                Dim desc As String = cards.Element("desc").Value
                Dim race As String = cards.Element("race").Value
                Dim image_url As String = cards.Element("image_url").Value
                Dim atk As String = cards.Element("atk").Value
                Dim def As String = cards.Element("def").Value
                Dim level As String = cards.Element("level").Value
                MsgBox(name & " " & type & " " & desc)

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Convert.ToString(name))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Convert.ToString(type))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Convert.ToString(desc))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@race", Convert.ToString(race))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_url", Convert.ToString(image_url))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atk", Convert.ToInt32(atk))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@def", Convert.ToInt32(def))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", Convert.ToInt32(level))

                command.Connection = conn
                command.CommandText = "insert into [" & decknametxt.Text & "] (name, type, [desc], race, image_url, atk, def, [level]) values(@name, @type, @desc, @race, @image_url, @atk, @def, @level)"
             command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML looks a bit malformed... Should look something like this.

```
<XML>
    <cards>
        <name>Majespecter Toad - Ogama</name>
        <type>Pendulum Effect Monster</type>
        <desc>When this card is Normal or Special Summoned: You can Set 1 "Majespecter" Spell/Trap Card directly from your Deck, but it cannot activate this turn. You can only use this effect of "Majespecter Toad - Ogama" once per turn. Cannot be targeted or destroyed </desc>
        <race>Spellcaster</race>
        <image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/645794.jpg</image_url>
        <atk>1300</atk>
        <def>500</def>
        <level>4</level>
    </cards>
    <cards>
        <name>Gladiator Beast Retiari</name>
        <type>Effect Monster</type>
        <desc>When this card is Special Summoned by the effect of a "Gladiator Beast" monster, you can remove from play 1 card from your opponent's Graveyard. At the end of the Battle Phase, if this card attacked or was attacked, you can return it to the Deck to Specia</desc>
        <race>Aqua</race>
        <image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/612115.jpg</image_url>
        <atk>1200</atk>
        <def>800</def>
        <level>3</level>
    </cards>
    <cards>
        <name>Malefic Rainbow Dragon</name>
        <type>Effect Monster</type>
        <desc>This card cannot be Normal Summoned or Set. This card cannot be Special Summoned, except by removing from play 1 "Rainbow Dragon" from your hand or Deck. There can only be 1 face-up "Malefic" monster on the field. Other monsters you control cannot declare</desc>
        <race>Dragon</race>
        <image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/598988.jpg</image_url>
        <atk>4000</atk>
        <def>0</def>
        <level>10</level>
    </cards>
</XML>
```

Personally I would load the XML directly to a dataset and then loop through the datatable. Something like this....

```
   Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
   conn = New OleDbConnection
   dbprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
   Dim databasePath = "Data Source = FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb;"
   conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider & databasePath
   Dim command As OleDbCommand
   Try

       Dim f as XmlReader= XmlReader.Create("C:\Users\1964\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\YGO Access Test v10\bin\Debug\MyData.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())

       Dim ds as new DataSet
       ds.readxml(f)
       conn.Open()
       command = New OleDbCommand()

            For each row as datarow in ds.tables(0).rows
                Dim name As String = row.item("name")
                Dim type As String = row.item("type")
                Dim desc As String = row.item("desc")
                Dim race As String = row.item("race")
                Dim image_url As String = row.item("image_url")
                Dim atk As String = row.item("atk")
                Dim def As String = row.item("def")
                Dim level As String = row.item("level")
                MsgBox(name & " " & type & " " & desc)

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Convert.ToString(name))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Convert.ToString(type))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Convert.ToString(desc))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@race", Convert.ToString(race))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_url", Convert.ToString(image_url))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atk", Convert.ToInt32(atk))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@def", Convert.ToInt32(def))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", Convert.ToInt32(level))

                command.Connection = conn
                command.CommandText = "insert into [" & decknametxt.Text & "] (name, type, [desc], race, image_url, atk, def, [level]) values(@name, @type, @desc, @race, @image_url, @atk, @def, @level)"
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
           Next
    Catch ex as Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

The dataset is easily viewed in Debug mode or displayed in a datagridview if you having issues with the data. (datagridview1.datasource = ds.tables(0))

If the XML is malformed the exception will indicate where it is malformed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately your code had some error (something like conversion of DBNull to String is not valid.) So I kinda changed it to this code but it only prints the name of the first entry of the XML to the access table. Do you think you know where I went wrong?

Comment: `Try
            conn.Open()

            command = New OleDbCommand()


            maxrows = dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count
            For i = 0 To maxrows - 1

                Dim name As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(row_count).Item("name")
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Convert.ToString(name))
    command.Connection = conn
                command.CommandText = "insert into [" & decknametxt.Text & "] (name) values(@name)"
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                row_count += +1
`

Comment: sorry don't know how to make it more user-friendly

Comment: You have a null field in your data. Simple fix ... for each item change the row.item(xx) to row.item(xx).tostring. The offending item will then be marked as 'NULL'. In future please run the code in debug mode and indicate which line has the error on